# Access denied security roles on media attach

Tags: media-library

I created a specific role inheriting the following sitecore roles :

[image]

I gave it the access to my media library folder and inheritance but i still can't click on the attach button, while i can detach and download the media.

Here is the error message triggering when i click on attach :

[image]
[EDIT]
The project is a multi-site instance with specifics hostnames. For information, I have access to the item in the back-office no matter what the hostname is.
Here is a sample of the cases where i get the errors:

```
"Attach media" functionnality via BO

| Hostname      | Role Admin  | Role User       |
|:-------------:|:-----------:|:------------:   |
| www.SiteA.com | Access      |    Access OK    |
| www.SiteB.com | Access      |    Access DENIED|  
| www.SiteC.com | Access      |    Access OK    |
```

Stack trace :

> [AccessDeniedException: Application access denied.]
>      Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.HasAccess(Boolean accessAllowed, String message) +158
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Attach.AttachForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +72
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>      System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +211
>      System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +337
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Attach.AttachPage2.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +66
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178

Could you provide me any help on this, please?

[EDIT 2]

[image: Screen from Access viewer on the Attach item]

Comment: Does the media upload work for Admins and other User Roles?

Comment: Its not the media items you are getting access denied to, its the tool to upload the images you are getting access denied to. I just went through this on the log viewer. Can you add sitecore\Sitecore Client Developing and 
sitecore\Sitecore Client Maintaining to the roles in your custom role.

Comment: Yes media upload works for Admin user. i added the two roles and it's doesn't works. I edited my question with more information.

Comment: Can you please log into Sitecore, go to the Desktop, in the bottom right click the database icon and select the Core database, then go to the Access Viewer (Start > Security Tools > Access Viewer). Navigate down to the `/sitecore/system/Field types/System Types/Attachment/Menu/Attach` item and for each of the affected roles (where it is not working) please supply a screenshot of the access settings that you see. Note that you should _not_ make any permission changes in the Access Viewer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since it has been more than a month after you asked this question, you may have already resolved this issue. However I would post the answer here for future reference.

**Short answer is that, `Attach` tries to open the 'Upload' dialog box. To resolve the issue, you need to give 'read' access to `sitecore/content/Applications/Dialogs/Upload` in the core database.**

I have also written a detailed post about it at https://akshaystechdiary.wordpress.com/2017/08/23/access-denied-for-attach-media-item-in-sitecore/

Please note that my Sitecore version is 8.2 - Update 4. Also, I just have a single site but still encountered the same issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to add the user in question to the Sitecore Client Maintaining role as it already has read access to the upload dialog box.  No need to edit security in the core DB with this route.

If that role exposes more functionality than you like @akshaey mahajan answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

To be able to attach media, your User should be a member of the Sitecore Role "sitecore\Sitecore Client Maintaining"

[image]

Comment: This worked for me and is a cleaner solution than modifying the rights to the Core database item directly. I'm running Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 161221).

Comment: One caveat with this answer is what @jeff-stoll references below--for some users this role gives them more than you are going to want. According to [Sitecore's Security Roles](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles) document, "This role is intended for Sitecore super-users and developers." Most of my users are not super users and developers, so I will also need to use the method akshay outlined for those users.

Comment: Just for your information, you will get a similar issue in Renderings Properties. By default, your Content Editors have no write access for the: /sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Rendering Parameters/Standard Rendering Parameters/__Standard Values